# Add usesClearTextTraffic = true on expo-react-native

Tags: react-native, expo

I want to add usesClearTextTraffic = true in my expo react native project.There is no AndroidManifest.xml project in expo-react-native.How I fix it?

Answer (score 10):

You'll need to use the `expo-build-properties` plugin

```
npx expo install expo-build-properties
```

and then add the config in `app.json`

```json
{
  "expo":
  {
  ...
    "plugins": [
      ["expo-build-properties", {
        "android": {
          "usesCleartextTraffic": true
        },
        "ios": {
          ...
        }
      }]
  }
}
```

Comment: To clarify, you need to install the `expo-build-properties` package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/expo-build-properties

Comment: This solution worked for me, all http and https requests were failing after upgrading expo sdk 47 to 50.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in expo in app.json, incase you are looking for an option to use http sites. I was stuck using a local ftp server which only had http. Hope this helps.

```
"plugins":[ [ "expo-build-properties", { "android": { "usesCleartextTraffic": true } } ] ]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).