# Axios Request works on Expo Go but not on built APK

Tags: android, react-native, expo

While running the app in Expo Go on my Android device, it successfully makes HTTP requests to the FastAPI server. However, after building the APK and installing it on the same Android device, the app does not seem to initiate any connections to the FastAPI server. There are no error messages or network requests visible, indicating that the app is not attempting to connect.

I have ensured that I've set "usesCleartextTraffic": true in my app.json to allow clear-text traffic in the Android build. Additionally, the FastAPI server is accessible via its local IP address http://192.168.1.233:8000.

Despite multiple attempts to rebuild the APK, the issue persists. I'm wondering if there are specific configurations or permissions that I need to adjust for Android APKs to make HTTP requests to servers running on the local network. Alternatively, could there be something else I might be missing in my configuration?

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77032415/17865804), as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75041731/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73963905/17865804) helpful.

Comment: The CORS dont seem to be the issue as I am able to access the api using the expo go application. The issue is when I build the app to an APK is where I run to the trouble of the app not even trying

Answer (score 1):

Just solved a similar issue with my expo App. I stumbled over this question a couple of times and want to leave my two cents, hope it helps...

Silly question but, when you say:

> I have ensured that I've set "usesCleartextTraffic": true in my app.json to allow clear-text traffic in the Android build

I assume you've installed the expo package as stated in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76708333/9810595)

In my case, using

```
usesCleartextTraffic": true
```

And building the apk without cache did the trick:

```
eas build -p android --profile your_profile --clear-cache
```

Comment: It works like a charm. If you have http server then you can definitely give it a try . If it doesn't work , check the github issue related to this : https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/25057