# Add usesClearTextTraffic = false on Expo

Tags: android, react-native, expo

It's very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76475785/add-usescleartexttraffic-true-on-expo-react-native). I want to set the usesClearTextTraffic value in AndroidManifest.xml to false using an expo managed workflow.

I followed the same steps and the AndroidManifest.xml still comes up with usesCleartextTraffic="true".

This is my app.json

```
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-build-properties",
        {
          "android": {
            "usesCleartextTraffic": false
          }
        }
      ],
      [
        "expo-notifications"
      ]
    ],
```

and I installed the `expo-build-properties` package.

I'm using EAS and Expo 48.0.0

Comment: Do things work when you build locally? Also, could there be an issue with Expo Application Services? There is this [issue](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/25057) (that is not quite closed even though it has that status, that might be relevant).

Comment: Ended up upgrading to Expo 49 and it's no longer a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Issue was fixed by upgrading to Expo SDK 49.